# ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently is not overwriting the files in a given directory

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, unzip

I have a solution for updating an application that uses the API DotNetZip (http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) for handling ZIP files. One method is to overwrite files in certain folders as follows.

```
ZipFile zipFile = ZipFile.Read(file);
    {
        foreach (ZipEntry zipEntry in zipFile)
        {
            zipEntry.Extract(@"C:\IASD\CantinaEscolar", ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
        }
    }
```

Where: `@ "c: \ SDA \ CantinaEscolar"` is where are unzipped the files inside the zip `(files)`.

Now, if the directory already contains a file with the same name that will be unpacked, the application is returning an error related to the file already exists in the directory.

```
System.IO.IOException: The file 'c:\IASD\CantinaEscola\nomedoarquivo.exe' already exists
```

`OverwriteSilently` This method should not override the unzipped files silently (without requesting user confirmation)?

Or: Is there any way to force this overwritten within the directory (-type f or something)?

If you possess any other tips on how to accomplish this task, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 3):

OverwriteSilently **can** overwrite a file.
It won't throw an Exception if the file is already present even if the the file is readonly.

What it cannot do is:

- overwrite if the unzipping is done under the credentials that does not allow it.
- overwrite when the file is in use.

The latter could very well be the case for the file "nomedoarquivo.exe". This executable could be running while trying to overwrite.